# I'm almost finished, but how to loop the entire program?

Tags: java, loops

My cash register program is nearly complete, it can process sales and returns and adds or subtracts this to the money in the register.

My only problem is that once I'm done adding values for example, the program closes and i cant figure out how to loop it back to the choice menu. I tried using a do loop and a do while loop but it yelled at me saying it had invalid input (probably because you have to press F to stop when you're checking out).

How can I loop this whole thing?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Assignment3_000848913
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> Prices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ReturnPrices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int totalRegisterMoney = 0;
        int Choice = 0;

        System.out.print("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Press 1. Process a sale");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Press 2. Process a return");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Press 3. Display Money in register");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Press 4. Exit");
        System.out.println();
        Choice = in.nextInt();


        if(Choice == 1)
        {
            //THIS LOOP READS IN ALL THE PRICES//
            System.out.print("Press F when finished.");
            System.out.println();
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the integer price of the item: $");
                int i = in.nextInt();
                Prices.add(i);
                System.out.println();
            }
            while(in.hasNextInt());


            int totalPrice = processSale(Prices);
            totalRegisterMoney = totalRegisterMoney + totalPrice;
            System.out.print("Your total comes to $");
            System.out.println(totalPrice);
        }
        if(Choice == 2)
        {
            System.out.print("Press F when finished.");
            System.out.println();
            do
            {
                System.out.print("Enter the price of the returned item: $");
                int j = in.nextInt();
                ReturnPrices.add(j);
                System.out.println();
            }
            while(in.hasNextInt());


            int returnTotal = processReturn(ReturnPrices);
            if(returnTotal > totalRegisterMoney)
            {
                System.out.print("Sorry, there's not that much money in the register.");
                System.out.println();
            }
            else
            {
                totalRegisterMoney = totalRegisterMoney - returnTotal;
            }

            System.out.print("You've completed the return.");
            System.out.println();
        }
        if(Choice == 3)
        {
            viewBalance(totalRegisterMoney);
        }


    }


    //END OF MAIN
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were getting that error when you did the do..while, you were doing it OK.

The problem is that after writing the 'F' to exit option 1 , the loop returns and tries to convert that 'F' into

```
Choice = in.nextInt();
```

This causes an error bucause a 'F' is not a number.
You would need to put an

```
in.next();
```

after your

```
while(in.hasNextInt());
```

This also would happen on option 2 in your code